# What XY coordinate system goes with EGM96 when projecting elevation raster in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, vertical-transformation

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.3.1.

I have an elevation raster in WGS84 and a national Z coordinate system. I need to project this DEM raster to the EGM96 Z coordinate system.

Which XY coordinate system goes with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data is in a [compound coordinate system](https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/glossary/CompoundCoordinateReferenceSystem); i.e. vertical data in one coordinate system and horizontal in another.  This is true both before and after transforming the raster to EGM96-relative heights.

The horizontal (XY) coordinate system can be anything you choose - though typically one would select a map projection tailored to the area of interest (such as a national grid or a [UTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system) projection).  Alternatively, you can keep the horizontal component in WGS84.